# Don't want to show my folder file structure from browser url

Tags: php, .htaccess, security

I don't want to show my images, zip files or any other files. Because all of these very important files.

Suppose my image url like it

```
http://www.example.com/users/upload/images/example.jpg
```

And if anyone can take below url and go with browser url then they can see my all other images.

```
http://www.example.com/users/upload/images/
```

I don't want to show my images files, Or i want to show some 404 page not found.

Can anyone know the solution of above problem?

Comment: This is a web server configuration problem, not a programming problem. What server are you using? For Apache, `Options -Indexes`. However, if you have sensitive files not everyone should be able to access, you shouldn't rely on keeping the URL obscure alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `.htaccess` file for the folder(images), which should have denied access with

```
Deny from  all
```

or you can redirect to a custom 404 page

```
Redirect /images/ 404.html
```

For more information,

```
http://www.sitepoint.com/htaccess-for-all/
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your apache config file:

```
<Location />
  Options -Indexes
</Location>
```

Comment: is there any option to redirect to 404 page not found, in the above situation?

Comment: Add: ErrorDocument 404 /yourfilename.html

Comment: Is there any effect gets while to show my images in my application?

Comment: nope. this just prevents user from accessing a list of images. if you want an error document, if /images/ is called, use ErrorDocument with code 403 (=forbidden) instead. So if a user tries to fetch /images/ an individual error message can be shown.

Comment: in .htaccess file just include Options -Indexes

Answer (score 0):

You can use .htaccess to do that. 
I guess `Options -Indexes` to your htaccess will do the trick.

Comment: is that "Options -Indexes" put in htaccess file? Is there any way to hide any particular file format? How can i redirect it to 404 page not found?

Comment: Yes you have to put this in an htaccess file or in your vhost configuration.
To hide a particular file format use `IndexIgnore` directive. And use `ErrorDocument` directive to redirect to a particular page.

Comment: ok. thanks. is there any effect gets on my application after does above configuration? like to show any images in my application pages

Comment: I don't think so, but test it to be sure :)
(I don't know if i was clear but you can use `IndexIgnore` only if you didn't put the `Options -Indexes`)
And be sure to put this configuration in the right folder.

Answer (score 0):

you can put a .htaccess file in that folder that contains just:

```
deny from all
```

That way you cannot open any file from that folder by url, but you can include them in php without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to adding `Options -Indexes` to your htaccess file, add a/an index.html or index.php inside any directories whose structure you are trying to protect. That way when the user navigates to them, rather than seeing the directory structure, they'll just get served the index file. The index file does not need to contain any code or text.